# eigenvalues of a VCV matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm having difficulty understanding this [material](https://www.visiondummy.com/2014/04/geometric-interpretation-covariance-matrix/) which states that the eigenvalues equal the variance components of the covariance matrix.

for example, a $VCV=\begin{bmatrix} 5 &4\\4 &6 \end{bmatrix}$ can be diagonalised as 
$\begin{bmatrix} 1.46 ~~~~~~~0\\0~~~~~~9.53 \end{bmatrix}$ which are the eigenvalues and they don't equal to the variance components of the VCV which are 5 and 6.

Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalues are the variances of the eigenvectors which may or may not be the original random variables. For instance, maybe your original random variables are $X$ and $Y$ but your eigenvectors are $\frac1{\sqrt2}(X + Y)$ and $\frac1{\sqrt2}(X - Y)$.

On the other hand, if the covariance matrix is diagonal (meaning $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = 0$), then $X$ and $Y$ are eigenvectors and the diagonal entries of that covariance matrix are just the variances of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Thanks! make sense now.